# Unable to synchronise Kafka and MQ transactions usingChainedKafkaTransaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, transactions, spring-kafka

We have a spring boot application which consumes messages from IBM MQ does some transformation and publishes the result to a Kafka topic. We use https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka for this. I am aware that Kafka does not supports XA; however, in the documentation I found some inputs about using a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` to chain multiple transaction managers and synchronise the transactions. The same documentation also provides an example about how to synchronise Kafka and database while reading messages from Kafka and storing them in the database.

I follow the same example in my se case and chained the `JmsTransactionManager` with `KafkaTransactionManager` under the umbrella of a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager`. The bean definitions follows below:

```
@Bean({"mqListenerContainerFactory"})
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory());
    factory.setTransactionManager(this.jmsTransactionManager());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager() {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(this.connectionFactory());
}

@Bean("chainedKafkaTransactionManager")
public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> chainedKafkaTransactionManager(
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager, KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager) {

    return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(kafkaTransactionManager, jmsTransactionManager);
}

@Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedKafkaTransactionManager", rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
@JmsListener(destination = "${myApp.sourceQueue}", containerFactory = "mqListenerContainerFactory")
public void receiveMessage(@Headers Map<String, Object> jmsHeaders, String message) {
    // Processing the message here then publishing it to Kafka using KafkaTemplate
    kafkaTemplate.send(sourceTopic,transformedMessage);

    // Then throw an exception just to test the transaction behaviour
    throw new RuntimeException("Not good Pal!");
}
```

When running the application what is happening is that he message keep getting rollbacked into the MQ Queue but messages keep growing in Kafka topic which means to me that kafkaTemplate interaction does not get rollbacked.

If I understand well according with the documentation this should not be the case. "If a transaction is active, any KafkaTemplate operations performed within the scope of the transaction use the transaction’s Producer."

In our application.yaml we configured the Kafka producer to use transactions by setting up `spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix`

The question is what I am missing here and how should I fix it.
Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Does your KafkaConumer have `isolation.level=read_committed`? By default, consumers can see uncommitted records. Generally, turning on DEBUG/TRACE debugging will help diagnose such situations. While not relevant here, `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` is only needed when a listenr container manages the transaction. Otherwise a simple `ChainedTransactionManager` is enough.

Comment: Thanks Gary. You have just saved myself from a big headache.. I was not aware that confluent Kafka I used to browse the messages was showing uncommitted messages as well. Please format tour comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumers can see uncommitted records by default; set the `isolation.level` consumer property to `read_committed` to avoid receiving records from rolled-back transactions.